# Build multiple targets with xcodebuild in parallel

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, gitlab, xcodebuild

I'm trying to xcodebuild multiple targets (but not all, just 3/5) in parallel to save time.

I tried already:

- do it locally on my Mac by starting background thread for every target and calling xcodebuild on it - no success, build time is the same as calling xcodebuild x times one after another
- do it using GitLab CI by creating separate jobs for every scheme - I can see 2 jobs running at the same time in GitLab UI but overall build time does not change

I call xcodebuild like this:

```
xcodebuild archive -workspace "ProjectName.xcworkspace" -scheme "SCHEME_TO_BUILD" -archivePath $ARCHIVE_PATH -allowProvisioningUpdates -parallelizeTargets -jobs 8
```

So is it even possible to build multiple targets at once and save some time?

Comment: Have you tried using xcrun xcodebuild?